# Xquery transformation on text data in response

Tags: xslt-1.0, xquery

I want to get a xquery transformation drafted for below data.. here as part of service response fault, I am getting below payload and need to capture the  data in ErrorCode element.

challenge that I am having here is, this is not part of a XML structure, its coming as part of CDATA tags.

Could you please suggest how I can get this value in a variable same.

Say I am getting this structure as part of $Fault and now need to assign ErrorCode in a new variable $FaultCode

$FaultCode = $Fault/con:details/con1:ErrorResponseDetail/con1:detail/ ********

I am not sure how I can capture this further detail element

```xml
<con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
   <con:errorCode>382502</con:errorCode>
   <con:reason>eceived an error response</con:reason>
   <con:details>
      <con1:ErrorResponseDetail xmlns:con1="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/transform/config">
         <con1:detail>
         <![CDATA[<Error xmlns="http://servic.abcd.net/V1">
  <ErrorCode>DATA_AVAILABILITY</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDescription>{"description":"No Cdata for )"}</ErrorDescription>
</Error>]]></con1:detail>
         <con1:http-response-code>404</con1:http-response-code>
      </con1:ErrorResponseDetail>
   </con:details>
   <con:location>
      <con:node>TestPPNode</con:node>
      <con:pipeline>TestPPNode_request</con:pipeline>
      <con:stage>Test Stage</con:stage>
      <con:path>request-pipeline</con:path>
   </con:location>
</con:fault>
```

Comment: So what does "capture" mean exactly? And which version of XQuery and which XQuery processor do you use? XQuery 3.1 has functions like `parse-xml` and `parse-xml-fragment` that allow you to parse escaped XML data, like in CDATA sections.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks for your response. I have modified the question to be bit more descriptive.  I am using basic qquert/xslt 1.0 version supported by my tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XQuery 3.1 with the `parse-xml` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml) you can use

```
declare namespace con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context";
declare namespace con1="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/transform/config";
declare namespace V1 = "http://servic.abcd.net/V1";



/con:fault/con:details/con1:ErrorResponseDetail/con1:detail!parse-xml(.)/V1:Error/V1:ErrorCode/data()
```

to get the string value `DATA_AVAILABILITY`, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e27 for demo.

With XQuery 1 there is not XML parsing which is needed to solve this properly but you can of course try to use string functions to extract the data e.g.

```
/con:fault/con:details/con1:ErrorResponseDetail/con1:detail/substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;ErrorCode>'), '&lt;/ErrorCode>')
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin.. Do you have suggestion how we can do with XSLT also.. as I might need to create a extra xquery file here to do this data transformation.

Comment: Well, XSLT (3) and XQuery (3) share functions like `parse-xml` so there is not difference in doing that in XSLT 3, the path expression `/con:fault/con:details/con1:ErrorResponseDetail/con1:detail!parse-xml(.)/V1:Error/V1:ErrorCode/data()` is the same (of course namespaces in XSLT are simply declared the XML way, as XSLT documents are XML documents).

Comment: I am trying to fit above suggestion but unfortunately my application is still on xquery 1.0 and there parse-xml function is not working. Would appreciate if you can suggest a way with 1.0

Comment: There is no good and complete way to solve that with XQuery 1, other than trying to implement your own XML parser if XQuery, but the data is simply text so you can use any string functions to try to extract values, see the edit for an example.

Comment: I am not sure what else u can help me here but everytime I try to use this code, I am getting this error .. line 10, column 60: {err}XP0004 [{bea-err}XP0004b]: Found type mismatch in expression. Only empty sequence satisfies type checking rules. Expected type: node*. Actual type: {http://www.
 w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string*   --- the sample file which you share, I can see its working there but as soon as I put in my Eclips which use XQury 1.0, it just give me above error.

Comment: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e27/1 has the other suggestion which I think should work in XQuery 1. You might want to add a tag for your specific XQuery processor or engine as perhaps someone can tell you based on the error message whether it fully supports XQuery 1 or how to rewrite the query so that the processor allows you to return a string.